# Using Wine to run Brawlhalla(windows only steam game) and it is not able to enable hardware rendering

Tags: wine, games, steam

Every time I run the game I get this error. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6kCv.jpg). I can Still play but it is very laggy and my computer should be able to handle this game

Comment: its Wine every windows game will not have same performance as windows has, some games won't run at all.

Comment: Try upgrading to the [latest wine](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and see if the problem persist. Also look: do you see any errors when the game is run from terminal? If you see nothing suspicious, try finding the game logs — perhaps there you could find some hint, like missing support for particular OpenGL version the game is using, or something like that. If you didn't find the logs, try, as the popup says, to contact devs, and ask where to find info for why the game was dropped to software rendering.